Using CEF in webview
im building an App which i deploy as two exe's which i generate with pyinstaller. The first exe creates a PyWebio-GUI, the second exe opens a webview-window to look at the GUI. I am restricted to use cef. My code looks like this:
import webview
from cefpython3 import cefpython as cef

screens=webview.screens
webview.create_window('App', 'http://127.0.0.1:1237', screen=screens[0])
webview.start(gui='cef')

However, i get the error message that "mshtml is deprecated" and in the GUI-window i get "Sorry, this website does not support IE browser. :(". But i explicitly asked for cef. Seems like the code is just ignoring what i set, i can also set gui='asdasda' or the other codes (gtk, qt, ...) and it will still tell me that mshtml is deprecated. Why does it not use cef?
Link to docs: https://pywebview.flowrl.com/guide/web_engine.html
I use python 3.9.19.
Thanks for any help.
